# Wordpress content displaying weird when using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I am currently doing some custom work on a clients wordpress site. I am using the code below to query the database which works fine. However, when i try showing the results it isnt working as it should. Basically i am trying to query the postmeta table to find info from a custom field i added, which in this case might be my name, andy. Once the system finds all the posts with the custom field value as andy, it should then use the id for those rows and display the title, content and date for each one. This was working fine until i viewed the page live and basically it is counting the amount of times my name appears, and echoing info from all of the rows, whereas i want it to only echo info from the rows that are publish. Can any one help, huge headache for me!:

PHP

```
<?php
        require_once('dbConfig.php');

        // This variable grabs the name in the URL
        $r = get_permalink();
        $r = explode('/', $r);
        $r = array_filter($r);
        $r = array_merge($r, array()); //reset keys
        $code = $r[3];

        $getName = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $code);
        $name = $db->real_escape_string($getName);
        ?>

        <?php
        $allposts = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_value = %s", $name) );
        foreach ($allposts as $singlepost) { 
            $wpPosts = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_title, post_content, post_date_gmt FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = %d AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_type='post' ORDER BY ID DESC", $singlepost->post_id) );
            $wpPostsDate = new DateTime($wpPosts->post_date_gmt);
            echo '<h1>'.$wpPosts->post_title.'</h1><br>';
            echo 'Post Content: '.$wpPosts->post_content.'<br>';
            echo 'Post Date: '.$wpPostsDate->format('jS F Y').'<br><br>';
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you just need a simple approach:

```
require_once('dbConfig.php');
            // This variable grabs the name in the URL
            $r = get_permalink();
            $r = explode('/', $r);
            $r = array_filter($r);
            $r = array_merge($r, array()); //reset keys
            $code = $r[3];

            $getName = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/", "", $code);
            $name = $db->real_escape_string($getName);

            $pages = get_posts('meta_key=post_author&meta_value='.$name.'&post_type=post&post_status=publish');

            $output = '';

            foreach($pages as $value){

                $output .= "<h1>".$value->post_title."</h1>";
                $output .= "<p>".$value->post_content."</p>";
            } 

            echo $output;
```

works exactly how i wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

First be sure you have exact value in `$name` before running select query and then try a single joined query like this:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT
          p.post_title, p.post_content, p.post_date_gmt
        FROM
          $wpdb->posts p
        RIGHT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta pm ON (pm.post_id = p.ID)
        WHERE pm.meta_value = %s AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND p.post_type = 'post' ORDER BY p.ID DESC
    ", $name);

$allposts = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

foreach ($allposts as $singlepost) {
    $singlepostDate = new DateTime($singlepost->post_date_gmt);
    echo '<h1>'.$singlepost->post_title.'</h1><br>';
    echo 'Post Content: '.$singlepost->post_content.'<br>';
    echo 'Post Date: '.$singlepostDate->format('jS F Y').'<br><br>';
}
```

Comment: Hello, i've just tried this with andy as the name, as i know that i wrote one or two posts and i am listed as the post author (meta_key = post_author & meta_value = andy) but just displays nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: also, if i do print_r($allposts); i get Array ( ) which doesnt seem right

Comment: Not to worry, i found a very simple approach, thank you for your help :)

Comment: @AndyHolmes Wonderful Andy. Also as your second comment, I updated my answer by changing to `RIGHT JOIN`. I think should return same result. Maybe...

Comment: Excellent, thanks :) At least i have another approach incase. Thanks for all your help